# Postman: How to retrieve value when key is array

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

Json Looks like :

```
{"discovery": {
          "[AppCtrl Global]": {
            "ScriptFileTypes": ".cmd,.bat,.vbs,.wsf,.pl,.py,.ps1,.tcl,.rb",
            "name": "test"
          }
}
}
```

Now I want retrieve Name value, by using postman

```
console.log(discovery);  // This is giving me complete object
```

But when trying

```
console.log(discovery."[AppCtrl Global]".name)  // Error
console.log(discovery."AppCtrl Global".name)  // Error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the name property by using `Object.values()` method

```js
let test = {"discovery": { "[AppCtrl Global]": { "ScriptFileTypes": ".cmd,.bat,.vbs,.wsf,.pl,.py,.ps1,.tcl,.rb", "name": "test" } } };

const values = Object.values(test.discovery);
console.log(values[0].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

You have an error on your sintax. If you want to access to a key from object, you have to do like this

```js
// use
const name = discovery["[AppCtrl Global]"].name;
// instead of 
const name = discovery."[AppCtrl Global]".name;
```

#### Option 2

If `discovery` only has one key, you can do that with `Object.values`.
Ej

```js
const name = Object.values(discovery)[0].name;
```

We do `[0]` if name if in the first key of discovery.

Hope, help you

PD. I dont speak english very well